# Sort dict in jinja2 loop

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm still learning jinja2 and flask and I'm having a difficulty using dictsort in jinja2.

So I'm passing this dict into a jinja2 template:

```
{'PEDD United': {'id': 37828, 'rank': 12, 'totalpts': 307},'Fc Mbonabushia': {'id': 205633, 'rank': 6, 'totalpts': 356},'FC Slurp': {'id': 933573, 'rank': 11, 'totalpts': 312},'KFC_Overijse': {'id': 38861, 'rank': 5, 'totalpts': 362},'Fc Paris': {'id': 1538051, 'rank': 2, 'totalpts': 396}}
```

What I want is create a table that is sorted by the value of the key 'totalpts'. I tried all sort of things and it just doesn't take totalpts into account when "sorting".

Here's one of my code:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        {% for team in league %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{team}}</td>
                {% for data in league[team]|dictsort(league[team]['totalpts']) %}
                <td>{{ league[team]['totalpts'] }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

by it doesn't sort anything in this case... Just print the value in the table without any order...

Anyone can help me out?

thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way you're doing this will not work, because as soon as you use `{% for team in league %}`, you're already using the unsorted dict and extracting the key,value pair from it.

I think `|dictsort` may not be able to help you in this case because you cannot sort by either key or value, but by the value's (sub-dict's) value for 'totalpts'.

Instead, you should sort this dictionary **before** passing it to the template, in the following way:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> league={'PEDD United': {'id': 37828, 'rank': 12, 'totalpts': 307},'Fc Mbonabushia': {'id': 205633, 'rank': 6, 'totalpts': 356},'FC Slurp': {'id': 933573, 'rank': 11, 'totalpts': 312},'KFC_Overijse': {'id': 38861, 'rank': 5, 'totalpts': 362},'Fc Paris': {'id': 1538051, 'rank': 2, 'totalpts': 396}}
>>> league = OrderedDict(sorted(league.items(), key= lambda x: x[1]['totalpts'], reverse=True))
>>> print league
OrderedDict([('Fc Paris', {'id': 1538051, 'rank': 2, 'totalpts': 396}), ('KFC_Overijse', {'id': 38861, 'rank': 5, 'totalpts': 362}), ('Fc Mbonabushia', {'id': 205633, 'rank': 6, 'totalpts': 356}), ('FC Slurp', {'id': 933573, 'rank': 11, 'totalpts': 312}), ('PEDD United', {'id': 37828, 'rank': 12, 'totalpts': 307})])
```

To sort the dict, we convert it into a list of tuples of (key ,value) using `.items()`. Assuming x is one such tuple, x[1] contains the dictionary with the 'totalpts' key.

```
>>> league.items()[0]
('Fc Paris', {'id': 1538051, 'rank': 2, 'totalpts': 396})  # = x
```

So now we sort the tuples using`x[1]['totalpts']`, using `reverse=True` for a decreasing order.

A dict itself cannot be sorted, it is an unordered data type - You can either use an `OrderedDict`, or you can simply use tuples:

```
>>> sorted(league.items(), key= lambda x: x[1]['totalpts'], reverse=True)
[('Fc Paris', {'id': 1538051, 'rank': 2, 'totalpts': 396}), ('KFC_Overijse', {'id': 38861, 'rank': 5, 'totalpts': 362}), ('Fc Mbonabushia', {'id': 205633, 'rank': 6, 'totalpts': 356}), ('FC Slurp', {'id': 933573, 'rank': 11, 'totalpts': 312}), ('PEDD United', {'id': 37828, 'rank': 12, 'totalpts': 307})]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your answer worked flawlessly and help me learn tuples :)

Answer (score 18):

You can sort a dict's items using the normal [`sort`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#sort) filter.

To sort by key use `attribute=0`:

```
{% for key, value in data.items()|sort(attribute='0') %}
  {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

To sort by value use `attribute=1`

```
{% for key, value in data.items()|sort(attribute='1') %}
  {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

To sort by a value's attribute use `attribute=1.name`

```
{% for key, value in data.items()|sort(attribute='1.name') %}
  {{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

That is the loop in the question will translate to

```
{% for team_name, team_attrs in league.items()|sort(attribute='1.totalpts') %}
  <td>{{ team_attrs.totalpts }}</td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I can't find anywhere in the Jinja2 documentation any mentioning of those magic `0` and `1`, but this answer allowed me finally to sort dictionary of dictionaries in Salt by `uid`:
`{%- for user,attr in users.items() | sort(attribute="1.uid") %}`

Comment: @TimurBakeyev this works as  the sort filter is applied to `data.items()` which returns a list of pairs. `0` is the first element of the pair (the key) and `1` is the second element (the actual value).

Answer (score 3):

You could sort it to an ordered list using [`sorted`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
league = sorted(league, key= lambda x: -league[x]['totalpts'])
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I get this error.

TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Comment: Indeed it work. However, Anuj answer is better because I can still access the 2nd dict with his method. Thanks for your help!